# Average for loop in loop PL / SQL

Tags: arrays, plsql

I am trying to calculate the avarage of durations from the last 40 days for diffrent IDs.
Example: I have 40 days and for each day IDs from 1-20 and each ID has a start date and end date in HH:MI:SS.

My code is a cursor which fetches the last 40 days, then I made a second for loop. In this one I select all the ids from this day. Then I go through every ID for this day and select start and end dat calculating the duration. So far so good. But how do I calculate the avarage of the duration for the IDs in the last 40 days.

The idea is simple. To take the durations for one id (in the last 40 days) add them together and divide them by 40. And then do the same for all IDs. My plan was to make a 2d Array and in the first array putting all IDs, then in the second array to put the duration and add the values for one id together. Then I would have added all the durations for one ID together and get the value from the array. But I am kinda stuck in that idea.

I also wonder if there is a better solution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you don't need loops nor PL/SQL - just *calculate* the average:

```
select id, 
       avg(end_date - start_date)
from your_table
where start_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 40
group by id
```

Drawback might be what you said - that you stored dates as `hh:mi:ss`. What does it mean? That you stored them as strings? If so, most probably bad idea; dates (as Oracle doesn't have a separate datatype for *time*) should be stored into `DATE` datatype columns.

If you really have to work with strings, then *convert* them to dates:

```
avg(to_date(end_date, 'hh:mi:ss') - to_date(start_date, 'hh:mi:ss'))
```

Also, you'll then have to have another `DATE` datatyp column which is capable of saying what "last 40 days" actually means.

Result (the average) will be number of **days** between these values. Then you can format it prettier, if you want.

Comment: I get one value (0,0023454... days) so all durations from all ids added together and divided by the count. But I want an avarage for every ID in the last 40 days. Like: ID1 = 0,2345 Days ID2=0,4562 days ID3=0,345 days etc

Comment: That's what the GROUP BY clause does.

Comment: I completly forgot to copy that part. I need to look if the data is currect but thanks in advance. I rly dont know why I didnt thought of that.

Comment: Ok checking the results. And it seems weird. I have 255 IDs but only get 80 ID (rows) outputed.

Comment: That's also because of GROUP BY, I'd say. Because, if there are multiple rows per each ID, query returns **only one row** for each ID.